# List inside other list performance

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of String:

```
List<String> names = new List<String> { "aa", "Bb", "cC", "DD" }
```

And a list of Categories:

```
List<Category> categories = service.GetAllCategories();
```

Where Category is the following class:

```
public class Category {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to know if all names are found in categories (using case insensitive):

```
bool check = names.All(x => categories.Any(y => x.ToLower() == y.Name.ToLower()):
```

1. Is there a way with better performance then this?
   I am not sure if Any inside All is the best approach.
2. Is there an alternative to using ToLower to get case insensitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Yes, you can use `!Except` + `Any` which is more efficient because it's using a set.

```
bool check = !names.Except(categories.Select(c => c.Name), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Any();
```

2) Don't compare in  a case insensitive manner by using `ToLower` but the right `StringComparer`.

Comment: elegant LINQ query

Comment: @Miguel If you want some explanation about the "why" in Point 2) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way with better performance then this? I am not sure if Any
>   inside All is the best approach

It depends on number of elements in collection. For small collections it could be ok to use `O(N2)` complexity as this operation might take a few ms.

For bigger collections and to improve performance you can use `HashSet<T>` :

```
var categoryNames = new HashSet<string>(categories.Select(c => c.Name));
bool check = names.All(x => categoryNames.Contains(x.ToLower()):
```

This `.Contains` will be a fast O(1) lookup changing overall complexity to O(N) but it comes with the price of time needed to create an instance of `HashSet<T>`.

-

> Is there an alternative to using ToLower to get case insensitive?

Yes, you can use one of `string.Equals` overload that accepts [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) argument :

```
y.Equals(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I feel this should have been the accepted answer because of alternative provided for bigger collection and putting an emphasis on saving on time with an O(1) lookup